# How do I get my own PowerShell script to run? Keep getting an error

Tags: powershell

I have tried:

```
    ##powershell.exe -executionpolicy -bypass
    ##Unblock-File -Path C:\SRM.ps1
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy  ByPass
```

NO matter what I do I keep getting this error:

> File C:\SRM.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file C:\SRM.ps1 is not digitally
> signed. You cannot run this script on the current system.

Im on the latest windows 11 version.
Using Powershell ISE
I am running the app as administrator.

What else is there?

Comment: Are you on an AD domain?

Comment: You cannot change the exceution policy for scripts from inside of a script!  ;-)

Comment: Have you tried `powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file C:\SRM.ps1` ?

Comment: Yes Im on an AD domain, Olaf yes I have tried that one...

Comment: Are you a domain administrator? Trying to fight GPOs is a bad idea, work with your admin, setup an exception for this script (an alternative user with a different policy etc). You might be able to work around the problem locally without the admin using invoke-expression or task scheduler - but your on shaky ground and could still have issues. Have you looked into signing your scripts to comply with the policy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your effective [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) is `AllSigned`, meaning that only cryptographically [signed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Signing) script files (`*.ps1`) are permitted to run, irrespective of whether they're local files or have been downloaded from the web (that is, [`Unblock-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/unblock-file) doesn't make a difference).

As [Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9196560/olaf) points out, trying to change the execution policy from *inside a script* cannot work if the effective execution policy prevents execution of that script to begin with.

Using the the PowerShell *CLI* ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for PowerShell (Core) 7+) with `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` *is* the right approach *in principle* if the intent is to override the effective execution policy *for the given PowerShell session (process) only*.

However, **overriding the effective execution policy from the command line / via 
[`Set-ExecutionPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy) fundamentally does *not* work *if your execution policy is controlled via GPOs (Group Policy Objects)***.

To determine if your machine's / user account's execution policy is controlled by GPOs, examine the output from [`Get-ExecutionPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-executionpolicy) `-List`:
If the values for scopes `MachinePolicy` or `UserPolicy` show a value other than `Undefined`, a GPO policy is in effect; if *both* values are different from `Undefined`, the `MachinePolicy` value takes precedence; the output order in general implies the precedence order.

In other words: Only if `Get-ExecutionPolicy`'s output starts with the following two entries can you override the execution policy using the command line or `Set-ExecutionPolicy`:

```
        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       ...
  CurrentUser       ...
 LocalMachine       ...
```

---

Short of modifying the GPOs to change the effective policy, there is no *direct* **workaround**, though you can use the CLI with `-Command` to submit commands that read a script file into memory and execute it there via [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression) (though this cmdlet [should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375)), though this won't work for scripts that rely on reflection features such as `$PSCommandPath` and `$PSScriptRoot` to determine their own file and directory path.